# MQ ksh shell script - trap error

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have ksh script as below.

```
if [ `uname` == "AIX" ]; then
    export LIBPATH_BKP_$$=$LIBPATH
    # Trap so that it will return the original library path when script exits
    trap 1 2 3 9 15 "export LIBPATH=$LIBPATH_BKP_$$; unset LIBPATH_BKP_$$"
    export LIBPATH=/usr/mqm/lib:$LIBPATH
else # All else will be either Linux or Solaris which uses LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH_BKP_$$=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    # Trap so that it will return the original library path when script exits
    trap 1 2 3 9 15 "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH_BKP_$$; unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH_BKP_$$"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/mqm/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH_BKP_$$
fi
```

when I execute it it says

tdestop.ksh[52]: trap: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=49648; unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH_BKP_49648: bad trap

tdestop.ksh- is the script name and its telling error at line 52.

Question is what is bad trap ? what is going wrong here ? I am not an expert in this area. Sorry if the question is really novice.

Thanks,
Dwija

Comment: so this only happens in a Linux (non-AIX) environment? Good luck.

Comment: And did you check it at https://shellcheck.net ? Be sure to include a #!/bin/ksh(93?) at the top of your script. AND have you confirmed that this error occurs only in the small sample of code you have posted? Good luck.

Comment: You don't have to worry about resetting environment variables as they are local to your script.

Comment: Thank you @shellter for your insight. The script is owned by another team and its a long script. I have pasted only the error prompting part. I dont have access to any AIX environment so couldn't conform if it happens in AIX as well.

Appreciate your comment.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond - this script is owned by another team. I dont have authority to change the way its designed. Thanks for your input. I should consider that when I write my own script. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
trap action signals...
```

e.g.

```
trap 'echo "I caught something"' HUP INT TERM
```

You have flipped the order of actions and signals, which is why `ksh` complains. You should instead be using:

```
trap "export LIBPATH=$LIBPATH_BKP_$$; unset LIBPATH_BKP_$$" 1 2 3 9 15
```

Comment: I have moved the signals after action which is export. Now how do I ensure the traps are working ? 

How can create some failure for the export action ? I would love to be able to test it. Thanks a million for your tips !

Comment: The comments indicate that the purpose is to reset modified variables when the script is done. Since all variables are per-process, this makes no sense: any changes would die with the script anyways.

Comment: So I would say the code is not efficient or not required. I have changed it. So far so good. No error and as you mentioned this statement has no logical contribution to the script.